# Is it possible to move my WordPress domain to .com without buying a new hosting

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

I have a WordPress website which has the .wordpress.com extension. Can I buy a new domain and link it to my WordPress website without buy a new hosting?

Comment: There is an option 'Map your domain without moving it from your current registrar.' on WP hosting. This is what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to change the name servers on the new domain to point to your current hosting.